# javascript Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var oldText, newText;
    $(".editable").hover(
        function()
        {
            $(this).addClass("editHover");
        }, 
        function()
        {
            $(this).removeClass("editHover");
        }
    );

    $(".editable").bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);


    $(".btnSave").live("click", 
                    function()
                    {
                        newText = $(this).siblings("form")
                                         .children(".editBox")
                                         .val().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

                        currentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                        $.ajax({
                        type:   "POST",
                        url:    "./musa_date_edit_ajax.php",
                        data:   "vidpubdate="+newText+"&id=" + currentId,
                        success: function(msg){
                            //alert("test ok");
                        } 
                        });

                        $(this).parent()
                               .html(newText)
                               .removeClass("noPad")
                               .bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
                    }
                    ); 

    $(".btnDiscard").live("click", 
                    function()
                    {
                        $(this).parent()
                               .html(oldText)
                               .removeClass("noPad")
                               .bind("dblclick", replaceHTML);
                    }
                    ); 

    function replaceHTML()
                    {
                        oldText = $(this).html()
                                         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
                        $(this).addClass("noPad")
                               .html("")
                               .html("<form><input type=\"text\" class=\"editBox\" value=\"" + oldText + "\" /> </form><button type=\"button\" class=\"btnSave\" >planifier</button> <!-- <button type=\"button\" class=\"btnDiscard\" >Annuler</button> -->")
                               .unbind('dblclick', replaceHTML);

                    }
}
);
```

IE/Chrome say:
**Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined**

referring to the following piece of code:

```
                newText = $(this).siblings("form")
                                 .children(".editBox")
                                 .val().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Weird thing is that it works perfecly fine on Firefox.
I guess it has something to do with the $this that seems undefined. But since I'm not a JS/Jquery guru I have no idea how to fix it on Chrome and IE.

Addendum:
Here's more or less how the HTML looks like:

```
<form>
    blabla
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>blabla</td>
            <td class="editable" id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $data['date'];?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<form>
    <table>
        <td>some useless stuff</td>
        <td class="editable noPad" id="1732">
            <form>
                <input class="editBox" value="22/05/13" type="text">
            </form>
            <button type="button" class="btnSave">planifier</button>
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btnDiscard">Annuler</button> -->
        </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your selector get some element ?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle example? It's unclear what the starting HTML would be.

Comment: Is your `form` is a sibling of `.btnSave` or `parent`?

Comment: `live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and removed from 1.9. Start using `on()`

Comment: Are you nesting forms? Some html code would be nice.

Comment: form is both sibling and parent I guess. I edited original post with HTML example.

Comment: form cannot be both parent and sibling :p

Comment: Do a simple test, put alerts like `alert($(this).siblings("form").length)` & `alert($(this).parent("form").length)` and see what you get??

Comment: both 0. Well, any way to fix this? :p I need both forms.

Comment: @PalashMondal use `console.log()` better.

Comment: @MusaPinar you'd have to provide the actual markup

Comment: `$(this.form).find('.editBox').val().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).closest("td").find(".editBox").val().replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Also, a suggestion. You can minimize your current code this:

```
$(".editable").hover(
function () {
    $(this).addClass("editHover");
},
function () {
    $(this).removeClass("editHover");
});
```

By doing this:

```
$(".editable").hover(
function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("editHover");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Might just be a typo in your shortened html snippet, but you are using the class 'editable' in the html and 'editbox' in the javascript.

`$('.editbox')` returns empty, so `.val()` returns undefined, so `replace()` causes an exception

To work out if the parent/sibling thing is correct, you need to show a little more detail in your html

EDIT: how about:

```
$(this).parent().find('.editBox').val().replace(...
```